# POST e GET no SSL

Tags: post, criptografia, get, ssl

Em um site, protegido com SSL, o POST e o GET também são criptografados? O fato do GET fazer parte do endereço, mesmo assim ele é criptografado?

Comment: Esta [questão](http://stackoverflow.com/q/198462/1244639) pode ajudar.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: "O fato do GET fazer parte do endereço, mesmo assim ele é criptografado?" No princípio, **tudo** é criptografado, [*talvez* exceto o domínio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) - o browser se conecta com o servidor a partir do endereço IP e da porta TCP, recebe um certificado, realiza o protocolo de aperto-de-mão (*handshake*) do SSL/TLS e *só então* - com o socket seguro aberto - realiza o protocolo HTTP (seja com GET, POST ou o que for). Ou seja, a camada que usa criptografia está abaixo daquela onde o protocolo acontece. Tudo o que está "acima" portanto é confidencial.

Answer (score 1):

como você já deve saber os dados GET podem ser vistos na URL como uma string de consulta:

https://exemplo.com/index.html?user=admin&password=whoops

Porque os dados são acrescentados à URL, há um limite para a quantidade de dados que você pode transferir.  Diferentes navegadores têm limites diferentes, teoricamente você pode ter problemas quando os dados chegarem entre  1 KB a 2 KB.

já Dados POST está incluído no corpo da solicitação HTTP e não é visível na URL.  Como tal, não há limite para a quantidade de dados que você pode transferir mais de POST.

Se sua conexão HTTP está usando SSL / TLS, os parâmetros também são criptografados, mas pode aparecer em outros lugares, como os logs do servidor web e teoricamente será acessível a plugins do navegador e possivelmente outras aplicações também.

Dados POST são criptografados.

As informações abaixo tirei dessa discussão do Google: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/758002.html

> ```
>  Os dados contidos em URL de consulta em uma conexão HTTPS são criptografados.  
>     No entanto, é uma prática não recomendada para incluir esses dados sensíveis, como uma senha em um 'GET'.  
>
>     Enquanto ele não pode ser interceptado, os dados seriam logado serverlogs texto plano no servidor HTTPS recebimento, e possivelmente
> ```
>
> também no histórico do browser.  e provavelmente, também estará disponível para
>   plugins do navegador e, possivelmente, até mesmo de outros aplicativos
>   no computador cliente.

```
     Sempre que possivel use HTTPS POST sobre se você deseja transferir com segurança da informação.

     Se você estiver usando uma biblioteca de criptografia para criptografar os dados, em seguida, você pode usar GET ou POST, mas
 isso vai ser uma dor adicional e você não pode configurar a
 criptografia corretamente, então eu ainda recomendo usar POST através
 de HTTPS, em vez de rolar  sua própria configuração de criptografia. 
Este problema já foi resolvido, não re - inventar a roda.
```

Outra opção que você pode querer considerar é usar um cookie seguro.  Um cookie que tem a flag seguro só é enviado através de um canal seguro, como HTTPS, e não é sniffable.  Esta é uma boa maneira de manter as informações de forma segura, como um ID de sessão.